# powershell execute start-process on remote machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

IDE: PowerShell ISE

I have a script which installs the chrome to a remote machine

```
#Script : Test01.ps1
Start-Process D:\Chrome\Chrome.exe -wait -verb runas  
write-host "Chrome is installed"
```

and I am executing the above script using :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MySystem18 -FilePath D:\Test01.ps1 -ArgumentList Process
```

The above script is working on local system (MySystem03) and remote machine (MySystem18).

But when I am executing this in MySystem18 it is not showing up the acknowledgement or cursor after the installation of chrome, even after successful installation of chrome on MySystem18.

Can you tell me how to fix it.

Comment: did you run the script under admin mode

Comment: yes the IDE is opened as Administrator, also in remote machine firewall is turned off., the issue is it is installing the chrome in remote machine(MySystem18) but scripting is keep on running on client machine(MySystem03).

Comment: Are you expecting the "Chrome is installed" message to appear on the remote machine?

Comment: You don't need runas with invoke-command, since you're likely admin anyway.  But the installer has to be accessible on the remote computer.  You'll either copy it there with copy-item -tosession, or use a scheduled task to access a share.  You can use install-package with an msi.

Answer (score 0):

D:\Chrome\Chrome.exe  is a path on your remote computer ? If not, try to share a dir with Chrome.exe named yourdirshared on your mysystem03 and replace by \\mysystem03\yourdirshared\Chrome.exe into your ps1

if always doesnt work, you can try to remove -wait my be...

if always doesnt work, are you try to specify credentil parameter?

```
$Username = 'username'
$Password = 'yourpassword
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "MySystem18" -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Start-Process D:\Chrome\Chrome.exe -wait -verb runas; write-host "Chrome is installed" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding -WindowStyle as a command option and that would run in a Window

Comment: Hello, please write more detailed answers without words like "maybe" that suggest that you don't know if this is in fact a solution or not.